# Migrating from log4j-1.2 to slf4j with log4j-2.6 binding

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to migrate an existing project from direct log4j to slf4j with log4j binding.
Also I am upgrading the the version of log4j from 1.2 to 2.6

Some of the common code change are :-

1.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
.
.
.
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SearchXYZ.class);
```

becomes

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
.
.
. 
private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchXYZ.class);
```

2.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
.
.
.
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XYZ.class);
.
.
.
logger.fatal("FAILURE", throwableObject);
```

becomes

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Marker;
import org.slf4j.MarkerFactory;
.
.
.
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XYZ.class);
private static Marker fatal = MarkerFactory.getMarker("FATAL");
.
.
.
logger.error(fatal, "FAILURE", throwableObject);
```

3. Removed Appenders.

and so on.

One place I'm stuck is Configurator file.

```
AppConfigLog4jConfigurator.configureForBootstrap();
```

It gives compile time error saying :-

> class file for org.apache.log4j.spi.Configurator not found

What does this function do? What is a possible replacement for this?

Comment: Apparently AppConfigLog4jConfigurator is not part of Log4j, so where did you import it from? If it's your application's class, you should also provide it's source code.

Comment: I think it is inside log4j only.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Configurator.html

I don't know if it is also there in log4j-2.x

Comment: @Danio AppConfigLog4jConfigurator  may be internal to my organisation, but I am having the problem due to the above package not being present.  AppConfigLog4jConfigurator  extends the Configurator interface.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not really sure why you are switching to the SLF4J API since the Log4j 2 API supports everything SLF4J does and much more. In my own code I have found that switching only requires changing the imports and LoggerFactory to LogManager.

Configurator is a class in Log4j 1 that is used to configure Log4j. It is similar to the Configurator class in Log4j 2.  You probably want to call one of the initialize methods.

Comment: According to [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) , log4j 2.x has depreciated many things like appender and some configurators. So I had to make changes everywhere in the code, while I don't know the code itself.

I got to know if I was using slf4j with log4j binding , I just had to replace the log4j jar and slf4j would take care of everything. That's why I thought of migrating to slf4j. I read that it is a good practice to have logging framework over slf4j so there is not a direct dependency in our code.

Comment: Log4j 2's architecture is very different than Log4j 1. If you are using SLF4J with Log4j 2 and have custom appenders or configuration you will need those even if you use SLF4J. Sure, you can use other Logging frameworks with SLF4J, but you can do that with the Log4j 2 API as well. SLF4J is just a logging API, but it will end up calling Log4j's API, so it is more efficient just to use it. It doesn't "take care of everything" for you.  It is a good practice to separate the logging API from the implementation, which is why Log4j 2 did it that way.